# Blackened and Flame-licked

Tags: grammar, adjectives, word-form

Context

> A deadly overnight fire raced through a 24-story apartment tower in London on Wednesday, killing at least six people and injuring 74 others, police said. Witnesses reported seeing residents throw babies and small children from high windows to people on the sidewalk in a desperate effort to save them from the flames.
>   .
>   The inferno lit up the night sky and spewed black smoke from the windows of the Grenfell Tower in North Kensington, where more than 200 firefighters battled the blaze. A plume of smoke stretched for miles across the sky after dawn, revealing the **blackened, flame-licked** wreckage of the building, which was still burning over 12 hours later.

Are both 'blackened' and 'flame-licked' Adj?

Answer (score 1):

They are past participles of their respective verbs used adjectivally, with the added complexity of the compound in **flame-licked**.

> The fire blackened the building.
>
> The flames licked the building.
>
> The building was blackened by fire.
>
> The building was licked by flames.

After those events took place, the building was in a blackened state and in a state of having been licked by flames, and we can use the past participle adjectivally to express that idea:

> Dawn revealed the blackened, flame-licked building.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, so these are Adj in this context.